# What is the taylor expansion of $\csc z$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

$\csc z = 1/\sin z $

The expansion of $\sin z =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} $ is known to me.

How do you find the reciprocal of a series representation?

The question is actually find the radius of convergence about $ \frac{\pi}{2} $ but I think I need the power series first.

Comment: Of course, there will be a problem expanding $\csc z$ about $z=0$ since $\csc 0$ does not exist

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the power series to find the radius of convergence. By general theory, if $f$ is holomorphic on a disc $\{ z : |z-a| < r \}$, the Taylor series centered at $z=a$ has at least radius of convergence $r$.

On the other hand, since the sum of a power series is itself a holomorphic function, it cannot converge on a disc containing a singularity (pole, essential singularity or branch point).

In other words, your power series will converge on the largest disc centered at $\pi/2$ on which $\dfrac{1}{\sin z}$ is holomorphic. This you can find without computing the series.